# GetListItem SPServices don't retrieve data

Tags: javascript, jquery, caml-query, spservices, script

i'm trying to retrieve data from Sharepoint using SPServices.
I created a list called "values" with two field: "Title" (text field) and "values" (numeric field).

I created a js file linked to a Content Editor Web Part and used this script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "values",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
<ul id="tasksUL"/>
```

When I charge the page I have no result.
I tried to put an alert of `XData.responseXML` and it return "Undefined".

How can I resolve it?

Comment: I would check the case of your list name, try Values. Also emitting XData would be wrong, you'd want xData.responseXML, case sensitivity in JS is important.

Comment: Thank you, I checked it. The name of the list is lowercase (values)

Comment: Are your references to jquery and spservices correct? Do your browser tools indicate any errors?

Comment: Yes, references are correct. My browser doesn't indicate anything. Blank page!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? In Chrome on windows use F12 to show these developer tools.

Comment: I have Internet Explorer...i can't install Chrome on the pc :(. How can I open Console on Explore?

Answer (score 0):

Check your jQuery and SPServices version libraries. I received the same error when using new versions of both libraries. I didn't receive the error using the older versions.

Error Libraries:
jquery-1.12.3.js
jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js

Non-Error Libraries:
jquery-1.8.3.js
jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js